# Primes and squares in a grid

Tags: mathematics, primes

i) Place thirteen different three-digit prime numbers in the empty cells of this grid.

ii) Now place thirteen different three-digit square numbers in the empty cells of this grid.

How many solutions are there of each instance?

Source: [https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Bernardo-Recam%C3%A1n/dp/048684241X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048684241X)

[image]

Numbers are to be read as in a crossword: across or down.

Comment: Are leading zeroes permitted?

Comment: No leading zeros!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a unique answer for the squares:

> 8-169-225-1
>  484-625-729
>  1-441-676-6

If there is a unique answer for the primes too, then I will say bravo!

Answer (score -2):

The number of solutions for squares are 77520 and the number of solutions for primes are

590080113475142976

[image: 28]

Comment: May we see one of each!

Comment: I added a picture to my answer.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a solution with 1 digit per white cell, like a regular crossword. That way there would be far fewer possibilities than you state here. This probably also explains why you're getting downvotes here. Maybe try again?

Comment: I think the downvotes may be because someone doesn't have a sense of humor.